# Mocking HTTP interaction with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, http, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to mock an http interaction/conversation with a selenium webdriver instance?

Suppose I want to point a WebDriver instance at some url "X" but want it to load some html "Y" instead --- without actually visting "X" at all (my application url "X" can be offline! But know what HTML its going to load anyway...). Is there a way I can do this? I mean, *without* creating a REAL http server to serve "Y" on some port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a (temp) file with the HTML contents, then create a URL object pointing to this file, and then just use WebDriver's get method on this URL

Comment: In that case, what about scripts/images on that HTML page (linked via an http://... src-attribute)? Can I mock out the data the browser sees for those too?

Comment: Has this technique been tested? Would be nice to see some sample code. Also a response to ManRow's follow up question would also be great.

Answer (score 0):

Xml mimic stub server can do it with few simple configuration, read the readme file for sample configuration.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlmimic/